# Why was The Dresden Files cancelled?

Tags: dresden-files

Even though the show wasn't very much like the books, I quite enjoyed *The Dresden Files*. But why was the show cancelled?

Comment: And that's why the licence fee for the British Broadcasting Corporation (BBC)is a superior model for funding a broadcaster. Excellent quality niche shows can be funded without having to chase mainstream ratings. Hopefully someone will pick it up and run with it again, in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2007 **Jim Butcher**, the author of the novels, announced the cancellation of the TV series on [his website](http://www.jim-butcher.com/posts/2007/dresden-files-tv-show-canceled) and linked to a [**TV Guide** article](http://www.tvguide.com/roush/Dresden-Sci-Fis-9835.aspx):

> ...it's official: The show isn't returning for a second season.
>
> A shame, but hardly a surprise, given the reticence to discuss the matter every time I brought it up to Sci Fi or NBC Universal Cable execs during the recent TCA press tour. In their world, **it's all about "running the numbers" (in other words: looking at the ratings and budgets, etc.) and to them, *Dresden* just didn't seem to measure up.**

Comment: This supports my long-running opinion that TV is merely an advertising medium with overhead in the form of interesting stories sprinkled in to keep the audience coming back.

Comment: @wbogacz Writers, directors, producers, actors, technicians, etc don't work for free. If not enough people are watching the show, advertisers aren't going to want to pay for ads on the show.  If they don't do that, how are all those people going to get paid?  I'm sure if they all wanted to do it for free, SciFi would have been happy to keep airing it

Comment: @Kevin - You understand me perfectly. Advertisers drive TV. What they buy is airtime. They're not really buying the show - the show fills the airtime surrounding what their product is - the ad. The airtime will be more expensive on a popular show, and they can choose to buy or not buy. This happens regardless of their feeling for the show.

Answer (score 0):

The show was cancelled because the built-in fan base found out in the first episode that it bore only the slightest resemblance to the fantastic books. This meant that it had to compete with every other show airing at the time to draw eyes, and it just wasn't that special. Had the producers actually made The Dresden Files, it would have been able to tap into the many many people who love the books.

Comment: Any way to substantiate those claims somehow?

Comment: Makes you wonder how important a source materials fans are to a tv adaptation, versus viewers only familiar with the show. I'd ask, but I'm afraid it would get closed as too broad.

Comment: i will say the show DID get me into the books, so I'm thankful for that :-D